# SqlDataReader only returning first row value why?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to return all values in column Test but somehow is only returning the first row value...

I tried to add dr2.NextResult(); to the code but it didnt help

```
SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "select Test from PrescTest ";

conn.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

SqlDataReader dr2 = command.ExecuteReader();
try
{
    while (dr2.Read())
    {
        // get the results of column "Test"
        string Tests = (string)dr2["Test"].ToString();
        TextBox15.Text = Tests +" ";
    }
    conn.Close();
}
catch (SqlException sqlexception)
{
    Response.Write("ERROR ::" + sqlexception.Message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write("ERROR ::" + ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: I'm sure it returns all rows. But you only add the last one to `TextBox15.Text`. In each iteration of the while-loop you create  **new** `Tests` string, so you end up keeping only the last one.

Comment: btw: try using some `using` statements for the connection, command and reader to correctly dispose of them, instead of trying to do it manually and - in the code shown - wrong.

Comment: @RenéVogt ann okayy u have a point. so how can I keep all the records in TextBox15 ?

Comment: Also, a Select query is executed by ExecuteReader. ExecuteNonQuery is meaningless here

Comment: @Steve Why'd you delete your answer? I thought it was good, though I'd also go into more detail about only writing the query inside the try block, not needing to close the connection both in the try block, using a using statement, and not directly tying UI code to data access code (this should be a method returning a collection of strings, should be more functional).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the values coming from the database.  See revised code below

```
  SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "select Test from PrescTest ";
    
    conn.Open();
    
    //Nothing to execute so you can scrape this line
    //command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    
    SqlDataReader dr2 = command.ExecuteReader();
    try {
string Tests = "";

     if (dr2.HasRows) {
     
      while (dr2.Read()) {
       // get the results of column "Test"
       Tests += dr2["Test"].ToString() + " ";
      }
    
     }

      TextBox15.Text = Tests.Trim();
      conn.Close();

    } catch (SqlException sqlexception) {
     Response.Write("ERROR ::" + sqlexception.Message);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
     Response.Write("ERROR ::" + ex.Message);
    } finally {
     conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Per some of the suggestions in the comments too, you should really think about imlementing using statements.  It does an automatic Close/Dispose on items such as sql conns, data readers, commands, etc. and is good practice.

Comment: Your approach in rebuilding continuosly the _Tests_ variable could be a problem if we have a lot of strings. Strings are immutable and at each loop two new strings are created. Better use something like a StringBuilder

Comment: `SqlDataReader dr2 = command.ExecuteReader();` is a dangerous call. The query could be wrong, the database could be unavailable, the table may be locked etc. That belongs in the `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigned the value and deleting the previous value of the textbox. Try with this:

```
while (dr2.Read())
{
    // get the results of column "Test"
    string Tests = dr2["Test"].ToString();
    TextBox15.Text += Tests +" ";
}
```